# TeX in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, latex

I would like to type [bra-keted expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation)

[image: bra-keted expression]

into the document. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Docs support a little bit of TeX syntax, but apparently not \langle and \rangle. It seems the best we can do is to use Unicode characters:

```
U+27E8  ⟨   Mathematical left angle bracket
U+27E9  ⟩   Mathematical right angle bracket
```

There may be a way to type these, but I haven't succeeded, and just copy-pasted them from [Wikipedia page for this Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Mathematical_Symbols-A)

They look good in a formula, except that, being ordinary characters, they don't scale with the size of the expression they contain.

[image: sample]

Comment: Yes, there is such a symbol in the Special Characters.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to search for "bracket" in the *special characters* option of the *insert* menu of Google Docs. There it has the angular brackets which you can use either in the text or equations.